# Robot Framework - Greater than or equal and Less than or equal

Tags: robotframework

I am trying to set value for giftAmt based on Don_Number value. When I try to execute always goes to first ELSE IF condition. Even if Don_Number is 70 it stores GiftAmt as 15 only. I tried with IF and also Run keyword. Please advise how to resolve this.

(example if Don_Number is 250$ then GiftAmt should be 25)

```
  IF  ${Don_Number} <= 100
  ${GiftAmt}  Set Variable  10
  ELSE IF     ${Don_Number} >= 101 or ${Don_Number} <= 149
  ${GiftAmt}  Set Variable  15
  ELSE IF     ${Don_Number} >= 150 or ${Don_Number} <= 199
  ${GiftAmt}  Set Variable  20
  ELSE IF     ${Don_Number} >= 200 or ${Don_Number} <= 299
  ${GiftAmt}  Set Variable  25
  ELSE IF     ${Don_Number} >= 300 or ${Don_Number} <= 399
  ${GiftAmt}  Set Variable  35
  END
```

or
Run Keyword If      ${Don_Number} >=101 or ${Don_Number} <=149     ${GiftAmt}  Set Variable  15
Run Keyword If      ${Don_Number} >=150 or ${Don_Number} <=199     ${GiftAmt}  Set Variable  20
Run Keyword If      ${Don_Number}>=200 or ${Don_Number} <=299     ${GiftAmt}  Set Variable  25
Run Keyword If      ${Don_Number} >=300 or ${Don_Number} <=399     ${GiftAmt}  Set Variable  35

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `and` instead of `or` in the conditions, otherwise for any number greater than 100, `${Don_Number} >= 101` will be evaluated to True causing value 15 to be selected. Another option a bit cleaner will be:

```
  IF  ${Don_Number} <= 100
      ${GiftAmt}  Set Variable  10
  ELSE IF    101 <= ${Don_Number} <= 149
      ${GiftAmt}  Set Variable  15
  ELSE IF    150 <= ${Don_Number} <= 199
      ${GiftAmt}  Set Variable  20
  ELSE IF    200 <= ${Don_Number} <= 299
      ${GiftAmt}  Set Variable  25
  ELSE IF    300 <= ${Don_Number} <= 399
      ${GiftAmt}  Set Variable  35
  END
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks Dan and Sujit.

Answer (score 0):

Dan has given you a crisp code but if you want it in more detail to understand it better then, You can just modify it slightly , as below:

```
  IF  ${Don_Number} <= 100
  ${GiftAmt}  Set Variable  10
  ELSE IF     ${Don_Number} >= 101 and ${Don_Number} <= 149
  ${GiftAmt}  Set Variable  15
  ELSE IF     ${Don_Number} >= 150 and ${Don_Number} <= 199
  ${GiftAmt}  Set Variable  20
  ELSE IF     ${Don_Number} >= 200 and ${Don_Number} <= 299
  ${GiftAmt}  Set Variable  25
  ELSE IF     ${Don_Number} >= 300 and ${Don_Number} <= 399
  ${GiftAmt}  Set Variable  35
  END
```